Running Python Script With VirtualEnv As Daemon Using .system file
[Unit]
Description="Twitter Automations Service"
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=source /root/twitter_bot/venv/bin/activate && python3 /root/twitter_bot/main.py
ExecStop=deactivate
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user target

This is the content for my twitter_bot.service file. For some reasons, the service exits after starting. Even after researching for a while, I have no clue why. Any help appreciated

source is Bash syntax, but systemd generally uses sh to execute shell script.

When you create a virtual environment, for example in /path/to/venv folder, you will have python interpreters in /path/to/venv/bin folder. In situations you haven't control on how to activate venv, you can directly use those interpreters in your shebang or in your command line. So you can change your unit file like:
[Unit]
Description="Twitter Automations Service"
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/root/twitter_bot/
ExecStart=/root/twitter_bot/venv/bin/python3 /root/twitter_bot/main.py
ExecStop=deactivate
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

